# Separating objects in a JSON array in java

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I have the following PHP code which is adding each three entries as a different object in the array.

```
  //Read the username and password from ServerRequest class
$username = $_POST["username"];   

    //Select all rows when the username match the input
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Chore WHERE username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "s", $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    //store the results of the previous query and create a variable for each column returned
mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement,$chore_name ,$point_value, $parent_username, $child_username, $created, $points_given);
$chore = array();

    //store the previous variables you created in the array (only the ones you want to use)

    while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {
      $t = new stdClass();
      $t->chore_name     = $chore_name;
      $t->child_username = $child_username;
      $t->point_value    = $point_value;

      $chore[] = $t;
    }

    //encode the array in JSON format
echo json_encode($chore);

//close the statement 
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    //Close the database connection 
mysqli_close($con);
```

However I am unsure as to how to create these into a listview in an activity. I have this in the xml file

```
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/choreList"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:typeface="sans"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/currentChores"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp">
</ListView>
```

And the following is the code I have so far but I'm pretty sure it's completely wrong and have no idea what section of the code to put it in.

```
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String user = extras.getString("username");


    //The URL is the location of the PHP file to validate a user
    String requestURL = SERVER_ADDRESS+"FetchChoreData.php";

    URL url;
    Chore returnedChore = null;
    try {
        //Opens the connection to the PHP files
        //Sets the conditions of the connection
        url = new URL(requestURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        //Opens an output stream to send the data to be verified
        // and then closes the all output streams and flushes the output writer
        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("username",user);

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        //saves the response code to ensure connection was succesful
        int code = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("code", Integer.toString(code));

        //Opens an input stream to retrieve verified data back from the server
        //Starts a String Builder to read the data off the input
        //Closes the BufferedReader once it has finished building the string
        InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null)
            stringBuilder.append(line + "/n");
            responseStreamReader.close();

            String response = stringBuilder.toString();
            Log.d("response",response);

            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);

            //Creates a JSON object from the string
            ArrayList<String> chores = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(int i=0; i < chores.length() ; i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);

                String chore=json_data.getString("chore_name");
                String username=json_data.getString("child_username");
                int points=json_data.getInt("point_value");
                String currentChore = chore + "\t" + username + "\t" + points;
                chores.add(currentChore);
                Log.d("Output", currentChore);


            ArrayAdapter<String> choreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, chores));
            setListAdapter(choreAdapter);

            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.choreList);
            listView.setAdapter(choreAdapter);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449887/how-to-fetch-datas-using-json-from-database-and-populate-it-in-horizontal-listvi

Comment: i think the problem is here :  JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response); you need to  use jsonResponse.getJSONArray("name of array"); after JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);